# Find closest value in a two dimensional array with python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

I found a script for finding closest value in array.
But i want the following. Finding the closest value in a 2d array.

```
myList = [10,15,28,35,55]
myNumber = 30
closest = min(myList, key=lambda x:abs(x-myNumber))
print(closest)
```

give my 28

so far so good.

My 2d array is the following

```
myList = [[0.145, 10], [0.156, 15], [0.254, 28], [0.322, 35], [0.421, 55]]
```

I want the following result.

```
[0.254, 28]
```

Is it possible?

Many thanks for every respons.

Louis

Comment: How do you define "closest" in the 2d case?

Comment: Just go one dimension at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it would be enough to change `key` function to following:

```
# considering each second item of each nested list
closest = min(myList, key=lambda x:abs(x[1]-myNumber))
```